# ipython call fileinput.input() with exception, but raw python can works

Tags: python, exception, input, file-io, ipython

I'm using python 2.7 and ipython2.7.
In ipython I tried:

```
In [107]: for line in fileinput.input('webrtc_log.txt'):print line
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-fd0ede841362> in <module>()
----> 1 for line in fileinput.input('webrtc_log.txt'):print line

    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py in input(files, inplace, backup, bufsize, mode, openhook)
    93     global _state
    94     if _state and _state._file:
---> 95         raise RuntimeError, "input() already active"
    96     _state = FileInput(files, inplace, backup, bufsize, mode, openhook)
    97     return _state

RuntimeError: input() already active
In [109]: fh=open('webrtc_log.txt')
In [110]: for line in fh.readlines():print line
Local Date: Mon Nov 28 13:03:47 2016
```

OK, the old "open+readlines()" works, but fileinput doesn't work.

I tried it again under raw python 2.7 command line, both works well. I wonder how ipython couldn't work with fileinput.input(???)

Comment: File object required store in a variable. Otherwise try open every iterator steps. Python say : Please don't kill me ! [Check document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) did you see any non variable usage ?

Comment: But why raw python command line works?

Comment: So `s = raw_input("Enter Filename :")` or `python my_awesome.py my_file.txt` all stored in a variable, first `s` second `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: Iterators not work on TEMP_OBJECT (got more index, value errors) check 1st suggestion ! @Troskyvs